# How to append list property of an object Realmswift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

I have two classes :

First One:

```
class GameObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var gameOutcome: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic  var Goal : Int = 0

}
```

Second One:

```
 class GamesObject: Object {
    let games = List<GameObject>()
}
```

On the addGameVC, I add a game save it on the GameObject with realm and appending the game to the list property within a write. My goal is to have a GamesObject including a list of all added game(s).So I can display them on a TableView. However when I add for example two games, what I get is 2 GamesObject, including each of them  two list of GameObject. I thought by removing the following line

```
realm.add(games)
```

would only append the game to the list property and would avoid adding a gamesObject. What am i missing it order to make it work ?

Thanks for reading.
[image]

```
class AddGameViewController: UIViewController{
        

        let realm = try! Realm()
         var realmGame = GameObject()
        let gamesList = GamesObject()

     @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
         realmGame.gameOutcome = matchOutcome
         realmGame.goal = (Int(goal.text!) ?? 0)
         saveOnRealm(games: gamesList, game: realmGame)
    }

    
    func saveOnRealm(games: GamesObject, game: GameObject){
        do {
            try realm.write {
                
                games.gamess.append(game)
                realm.add(game)
                realm.add(games)
                
            }
        } catch {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. So you want to add your games to the same `GamesObject`? Why even have a `GamesObject` then? You could just have a bunch of `GameObject`s in the Realm and get all of them by doing `realm.objects(GameObject.self)`. Will there ever be multiple `GamesObject`s containing different `GameObjects`?

Comment: Because I will do a list of list for my sessionsOFGames . From the reading I have to make 3 classes since real does not support multidimensional array.

Comment: From what I understand: each time a `AddGameViewController` is presented, a new `GamesObject` should be created and added to realm, and the add game button on that VC should add games only to that `GamesObject`. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: The logic I have is: `GamesObject` will always have only one Object. Because I have a Save session Button, when it pressed I grab the content of `GamesObject`, will append it to another list Which will be a 'sessionObject' and save it. When it's saved, I delete the object from `gameObject`. And restart again. But for the purpose of my question your answer is correct. I am trying different things with realm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code produces this behaviour because the add button will add a new `GamesObject` into realm every time. To fix this, you need to only put the `GamesList` into Realm if it is the first time you are adding a game.

You should also create a new `GameObject` each time you press the add button.

```
class AddGameViewController: UIViewController{
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let gamesList = GamesObject()

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let realmGame = GameObject() // I moved realmGame inside the button action
        realmGame.gameOutcome = matchOutcome
        realmGame.goal = (Int(goal.text!) ?? 0)
        saveOnRealm(game: realmGame)
    }

    
    func saveOnRealm(game: GameObject){
        do {
            try realm.write {
                if gamesList.gamess.isEmpty { // first time
                    realm.add(gamesList)
                }
                gamesList.gamess.append(game) // this also adds game into realm
                
            }
        } catch {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```